# How to check what a query is outputing in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the below code:

`query_posts('category_name='.$settings["categoriesmain1"].'&posts_per_page=1');`

And i need to know how do i do `var_dump` on this query for checking what is outputting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `var_dump`, simply pass the expression into the `var_dump` function.

```
var_dump(query_posts('category_name='.$settings["categoriesmain1"].'&posts_per_page=1'));
```

You can also store the output of your expression to a variable, then `var_dump` the variable.

```
$result = query_posts('category_name='.$settings["categoriesmain1"].'&posts_per_page=1');
var_dump($result);
```

Check out the [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/var_dump) manual page.

If `var_dump` is too hard to read, you can also use the [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function for a more human readable output.

Additionally, if you are outputting the `var_dump` or `print_r` in a browser, it can help to wrap it with html `pre` tags to remove default browser formatting.